# How to ensure attribute is updated only once in Rails 3 Active Record?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Wondering what could be the best way to handle situations where I need to update particular column and once updated it should not allow user to update again.

I tried using ***changed?*** method which checks for record that has been changed and not yet saved. But this would not check a particular attribute in that row.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could do name_changed? to check if attribute 'name' changed

Comment: @Anton I tried this but was getting **NoMethodError: undefined method** instead when checking for particular attribute.

Comment: Could you post exactly what you did and the console output? Thanks

Comment: @Anton It gives 1.8.7-p374 :005 > user.name_changed?  => false  But actually it is checking for whole row I assume because I did change the value. So now instead I am checking for updated_at field to check if the row was updated or not

Comment: Sidenote: it's been almost **4 years** since Ruby 1.8.7 is no longer maintained (and 3 years since extended maintenance ended). Consider upgrading.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Agreed. It is a legacy application which needed some enhancements. Thanks for input.

Comment: @Anton 's solution should do the trick. When are you checking _changed? add a callback `before_save :validate_name_changed` and check in that method whether it is changed or not, it should give proper output. If it returns true, you need to throw validation error.

Answer (score 2):

```
rails g migration add_value_changed_to_YOUR_TABLE_NAME value_changed:boolean
```

set in the generated file

```
default: false
```

and run the migration.

And now, once the value is changed, update this `value_changed` to `true`:

```
before_update :update_value_changed, :check_value_changed

private

def update_value_changed
  update(value_changed: true) unless value_changed
end

def check_value_changed
  if value_changed
    do_something_like_raise_error_or_do_not_save_changes
  else
    something_else
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @AndreyDeineko. I will try this out.  Meanwhile another workaround that I thought for ensuring that row was updated, I am checking for **updated_at** field to check if the row was updated or not.

Comment: @EktaVerma not good idea because you can update the row multiple times but the column you're interested in can be unchanged.

Comment: Sure yes, not a good approach to use updated_at in such case. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you have user class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :check_name_not_changed

  private
  def check_name_not_changed
    if self.name.present? && self.name_changed?
      errors.add(:name, "can not be updated")
    end
  end
end
```

I am assuming that the name attribute was some how set before.